# Github statuses examples

Tags: git, github, jenkins, github-api

I´m trying to use github statuses, but the [documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/) is not clear enough

Let´s say that my repo project is https://github.com/politrons/proyectV

They claim in the documentation that the post it should be

```
POST /repos/:owner/:repo/statuses/:sha
```

With a body

```
{
  "state": "success",
  "target_url": "https://example.com/build/status",
  "description": "The build succeeded!",
  "context": "continuous-integration/jenkins"
}
```

So in my case I´m trying

POST https://github.com/repos/politrons/proyectV/statuses/1

With Body

```
{
      "state": "success",
      "target_url": "https://example.com/build/status",
      "description": "The build succeeded!",
      "context": "continuous-integration/jenkins"
    }
```

But github return 404.

Any idea what I´m doing wrong? Some curl examples about this it would be great!!

EDITED:

I create a pull request on branch Test-status and when I try

```
   curl -v -X GET "https://api.github.com/repos/politrons/proyectV/pulls/1"
```

I recieve the json with a lot of information. Then I´m getting the sha information of the header and send this POST command

```
curl --request POST --data '{"state": "success", "description": "It works!", "target_url": "http://localhost"}' https://api.github.com/repos/politrons/projectV/statuses/5f4927adcfdc238ba8f46442b737d8ab912cc6ee
```

But then I receive

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

Comment: "1" is not a valid SHA

Comment: @Flimzy take a look what I did please. Still does not work

Comment: @paul pull requests are identified by their number—I've updated my answer for you.

Answer (score 6):

"1" is unlikely to be a commit SHA in your repository—note that statuses are set on *commits*, not on pull requests, so should you want to set the status on a pull request, you actually want to set it on the head commit of that pull request.

Using the API to get your pull request (assuming it's pull request "1"):

```
GET /repos/politrons/proyectV/pulls/1
```

In `curl`:

```
curl -X GET https://api.github.com/repos/politrons/proyectV/pulls/1
```

Allows us to get the head SHA:

```
"head": {
    "label": "new-topic",
    "ref": "new-topic",
    "sha": "6dcb09b5b57875f334f61aebed695e2e4193db5e",
    ...
}
```

Which is what you actually set the status on:

```
POST /repos/politrons/proyectV/statuses/6dcb09b5b57875f334f61aebed695e2e4193db5e
```

In `curl`:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"state": "success", ...}' https://<token>:x-oauth-basic@api.github.com/repos/politrons/proyectV/statuses/6dcb09b5b57875f334f61aebed695e2e4193db5e
```

Comment: could you please paste the whole url on your examples, using curl -v -X GET "http://api.github.com/repos/politrons/proyectV/pulls/1"
 is not returning that json, thanks

Comment: Thanks!, check the edit in my question please, now I have a problem with the post

Comment: You probably need to provide your token to the post request—I've updated the example `curl` command. Substitute `<token>` with your personal access token.

Comment: it´s possible make the authentication with username:password? if I try this  curl --request POST --data '{"state": "success", "description": "It works!", "target_url": "http://localhost"}' https://politrons:password@api.github.com/repos/politrons/projectV/statuses/5f4927adcfdc238ba8f46442b737d8ab912cc6ee Still have the same error

Comment: You can use [basic authentication using the `-u` flag to `curl`](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication), but I'd advise the access token method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126614/discussion-between-paul-and-kfb).

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, was getting JSON parsing error repeatedly after trying, made little change.

import json
data = {
 "state":"pending", 
 "context":"Testing Automation BVT",
}

"curl -H 'Authorization: token AUTHCODE' --data '" + json.dumps(data) + "' -X POST https://github.com/api/v3/repos/repo_name/statuses/shaValue"

This works for me. Need to pass json.dumps data as the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub returns `404 Not Found` if your token doesn't have permission to set statuses. Make sure you create a token with the `repo:status` scope.